# TFS compare options

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there an option in TFS to compare while not returning whitespace differences? ie. linebreaks, tabs set differently.

SourceSafe had this option, but I cannot find it in TFS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> Configure Users Tools.. ->

Add "%5 /ignorespace" to the arguments as per this post: [Whitespace in Team System Compare Results](http://www.controlstatements.com/2009/03/whitesapce-in-team-system-compare.html)

[You can run `diffmerge /?` to see other options]

A somewhat better option (IMO) is to replace the out-of-the-box diff tool with the free SourceGear [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) tool, or with BeyondCompare.

If you opt to use the SourceGear's tool, then the command line options (as of 8/17/2011) for Studio 2010 is:

```
-caption=%1 -nosplash -ro2 -shex -t1=%6 -t2=%7 %1 %2
```

For the merge, remove the **-ro2** (readonly) option

Comment: I tried with DiffMerge 3.3, it says 'merge arguments must contain %4'. Adding that works fine.